# Booting Ubuntu from a USB device even when BIOS have no option for doing so

Tags: boot

I have an older BIOS setup in my laptop which does not have **boot from a usb device** option.
Can I still boot from a usb device?

BIOS version: Toshiba V1.40  Date: 26-Apr-2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a PLoP Boot Manager CD that can be used to boot from your USB Flash Drive. This is useful for computer systems that do not support booting from USB in BIOS.  The PLoP Boot Manager works by first loading essential USB drivers,  CD/DVD drivers, and Hard Disk Drivers. The user is then presented with a (Boot Menu) menu of possible boot devices detected by PLoP. The user can then proceed to select a device to try and boot from.

[image]

**How to Create a PLoP Boot Manager CD**

- [Download](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) PLoP Boot manager, and extract the files from the Zip to
  your Desktop
- Burn the plpbt.iso to a CD using your favorite CD/DVD burning
  software
- Insert your Newly created PLoP Boot CD and your  pre-prepared Linux
  USB Flash Drive
- Reboot your PC and set your System BIOS to boot from the CD
- If all goes as planned, you should now be presented with an alternate
  Boot Manager similar to the one pictured above that can be used to
  boot your USB Flash Drive or other device.

Note: In some cases the Flash Drive will actually appear as a hard disk.

[source and official site](http://www.plop.at/)

Comment: You are welcome. consider to mark as answer if it help and up is appreciated